# SignalR on Mono (Linux Ubuntu)

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono, signalr, .net-4.5

I am having a hard time referencing the SignalR in my ASP.Net (4.5) application that I run on Mono (Linux Ubuntu). When I tries to add SignalR from nuget packages, then I get the following error: "**Could not install package 'jQuery 1.6.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**" Then I tried to install SignalR from source. I followed the instruction given on this page **https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR** to install SignalR. After that, I created a sample project as described here: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr#setup**. However, when I open my browser it says that  could not be found (this is the script referenced in my index.html file). I couldn't find that file, it seems this file is autogenerated. I am really stuck on this issue, not sure how to resolve it.
Not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed the same tutorial (**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr#setup**) on windows and it worked fine.

Comment: Publish from Windows side as binaries and deploy to Linux.